# Using a loop to create a new column and fill the items based on matching

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a data frame and I tried to use a `for` loop to create a new column and fill it with gram negative and gram positive by matching species in column 2. I know how to do with `dplyr`, but I want to use loop to improve my understanding for coding. here is my code:

```
species_abundance<-data.frame(
ID=c(1,2,3,4,5),
Genus = c("Sphingopyxis marina","Loktanella salsilacus",
          "Paracoccus chinensis","Bacillus","Streptomyces"))
```

and output is like

```
species_abundance<-data.frame(
ID=c(1,2,3,4,5),
Genus = c("Sphingopyxis marina","Loktanella salsilacus",
          "Paracoccus chinensis","Bacillus","Streptomyces")),
Grams_staining=c("grams_negative, grams_negative, grams_negative,grams_positive, grams_positive)
```

I tried with this code, but I didnt get my expected results, kindly help me in what all way we can loop to get results, so I can improve my learning.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(species_abundance)) {# for-loop over columns
  if (species_abundance[i,2] == "Sphingopyxis marina"&&
      species_abundance[i,2] == "Loktanella salsilacus"&&
      species_abundance[i,2] == "Paracoccus chinensis"){
      print("grams_negative")
  }
  
  else {
    species_abundance[i,2] == "Bacillus"{
     print("grams_positive")
  }  
}
```

Comment: your `if .. && .. &&` construct requires that something matches ALL of those, not one of those.  I would try `if(species_abundance$Genus[i] %in% c("Sphingopyxis marina", "Loktanella salsilacus", "Paracoccus chinensis"))`.     You also need a way to allocate the result to the data frame  (e.g. `species_abundance$Grams_staining[i] <- `)

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Thank you, its working, can we use or | construct insted using %in%  or ==, asking just to know how else I can work

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen, Also, I got this warning, 
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `Grams_staining`. 
Kindly explain the solution
Thanks

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen, Thank you, is there any way to change the position of column of Gramstaining, while looping, I mean if I want to put in first position than how will be the loop structure. Kindly reply, Thanks in advance

Comment: The order of columns doesn't matter really until you need to display the data, but in general you can do something like: `mydata <- mydata[,c(3,1,2)]` to select which columns to keep and in which order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this approach. First, define which genus/species should be identified as gram positive and gram negative, then use `%in%` in your `for` loop to print:

Define gram positive/negative (based on your loop in your question, can be anything).

```
gramneg <- c("Sphingopyxis marina", "Loktanella salsilacus", "Paracoccus chinensis")
grampos <- c("Bacillus", "some_other_genus")
```

For loop

```
for(i in seq_along(species_abundance$Genus)){
  if(species_abundance$Genus[i] %in% gramneg){
    print("gram_negative")
  } else {
    if(species_abundance$Genus[i] %in% grampos){
    print("gram_positive")}
     else {
    print("Not in in gram positive or gram negative list")
     }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
# [1] "gram_negative"
# [1] "gram_negative"
# [1] "gram_negative"
# [1] "gram_positive"
# [1] "Not in in gram positive or gram negative list"
```

Data

```
species_abundance <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                                Genus = c("Sphingopyxis marina","Loktanella salsilacus",
                                          "Paracoccus chinensis","Bacillus","Streptomyces"))
```